# Bluetooth peripheral is getting disconnecting frequently in iOS but not in android?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, disconnect

We develop BLE 4.0 peripheral based products. We are facing so many disconnection issues when we try to connect to ble peripheral from iOS. 
My hardware team kept connSupervisionTimeout value 20s for android and 6s per iOS(As per apple guidelines,
https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf).  Initially we used to connect two ble devices at once from both android and iOS apps. Since both apps faced so many disconnection issues we are connecting to only one peripheral(BLE1) now, and connecting to other peripheral(BLE2) from BLE1. Now android app is not facing any disconnection issues. But when it comes to iOS we are facing still disconnection issues. Do I need to set parameters from my iOS app? or my hardware team need to change parameters only for iOS? I am using iOS 8.4 and iPhone 5S. Will these issues getting resolved, If I upgrade my iPhone to iOS 9?

Comment: Does the disconnect occur when you are trying to establish the connection or after you have discovered characteristics?

Comment: Surely It is not disconnecting when I try to establish connection. It is working fine for some time after connection and I am able to send characteristics and receive notifications. But after some It is getting disconnected randomly.

Comment: You could use TSI  https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/